# Selecting the last three numbers from a user input

Tags: python

For this task I have to take a seven digit input called account number and use the last three digits to return a disk storage location, my code looks like this so far:

```
Account_num = int(input("Enter account number: "))                    
Disk = Account_num[-3:]
if Account_num <= 99999999:
    print("Your disk storage location is:",Disk
          )
else:
    print("Invalid account number entred")
```

It should also ask the user to input another account code and if the disk storage location is full, respond with an error message. 
what it should return is:

```
"Your disk storage location is" (three digit number)
"Enter another account number: "
```

but instead it returns:

```
    Disk = Account_num[-3:] TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

I know hardly anything about coding so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Should say `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable` because you cant do `[-3:]` on an int.

Answer (score 1):

Well `Account_num` is of type `int` and the `[]` slicing notation you're trying to use is supported for sequences (i.e objects that contain other objects).

In order to get the last *three* digits from a number you can use the **[`%`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)** operator that yields the remainder from the division, with `1000`:

```
Disk = Account_num % 1000
```

So for a given `Accound_num = 9230939`

```
Disk = Account_num % 1000
Print(Disk) # prints 939
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just cast your input later

```
>>> Account_num = input("Enter account number: ")
Enter account number: 12345
>>> Disk = int(Account_num[-3:])
>>> Disk
345
```

If you do this, though, you'll need to also convert the Account_num in your comparison

```
if int(Account_num) <= 99999999:
```

Answer (score 0):

You input

```
Account_num = int(input("Enter account number: "))
```

However, you try to process it as a string. This would work

```
Account = input("Enter account number: ") # string                 
Account_num = int(Account) # Now an int     
Disk = int(Account[-3:]) #  Make this an int also for use later
if Account_num <= 99999999:
    print("Your disk storage location is:", Disk)
else:
    print("Invalid account number entred")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use [-3:] on an int, but you can on a string so just get the input and then cast to a string to grab the last three characters and then cast to an int.

```
Account_num = input("Enter account number: ")
Disk = int(str(Account_num)[-3:])
if Account_num <= 99999999:
    print("Your disk storage location is:",Disk
          )
else:
    print("Invalid account number entred")
```